# php empty() is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, is-empty

I am having an unusual issue, one I really cannot believe is actually happening, but it is happening and am not able to find the way out of it. Please help me if someone knows what am I doing wrong.

I need to have an array `$EmpExists=array();`, which shows results after checking the database for all the businesses that do they have employees associated to them or not. I am using php to get a few values out of database and am checking if the value is empty or not. I have following Tables and Rows of data in them:

```
Table `EmployeeList`
Columns   EmpID       BusinessID
Row 1 `emp-000001`,`business-000001`
Row 2 `emp-000002`,`business-000002`



Table `BusinessList`
Columns    BusinessID
Row 1   `business-000001`
Row 2   `business-000002`
Row 3   `business-000003`
```

I am using following php code to call list of businesses:

```
<?php
$BusinessIDforthis = array();
$select_BusinessIDs = "SELECT BusinessID FROM BusinessList ORDER BY BusinessID ASC;";
$select_BusinessIDs_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_BusinessIDs);
if (!$select_BusinessIDs_query) {
    die ("Database query for searching BusinessID failed.");
}
while ($BusinessIDs_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_BusinessIDs_query)) {
    $BusinessIDforthis[] = $BusinessIDs_array["BusinessID"];
}
```

This gives me an array of `BusinessID` and then I use following php code to get the `EmpID` of employees for the `BusinessID`

```
$EmpID = '';
$EmpExists = array();
$EmpIDRecord = array();
foreach ($BusinessIDforthis as $x) {
    $select_EmpID = "SELECT EmpID FROM EmployeeList WHERE BusinessID='{$x}';";
    $select_EmpID_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_EmpID);
    if (!$select_EmpID_query) {
        die ("Database query for searching EmpID failed.");
    }
    while ($EmpID_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_EmpID_query)) {
        $EmpID = $EmpID_array["EmpID"];
        if (empty($EmpID)) {
            array_push($EmpExists, 'EmpNotExists');
            array_push($EmpIDRecord, 'Employee does not exist.');
        } else {
            array_push($EmpExists, 'EmpExists');
            array_push($EmpIDRecord, $EmpID);
        }
        $EmpID = '';
    }
}
```

Now `$EmpExists=array();` shows an array with following answers:

```
Array
(
[0]=> EmpExists
[1]=> EmpExists
[2]=> EmpExists
)
```

and `$EmpIDRecord=array();` shows an array with following answers:

```
Array
(
[0]=> emp-000001
[1]=> emp-000002
)
```

and `$BusinessIDforthis=array();` shows an array with following answers:

```
Array
(
[0]=> business-000001
[1]=> business-000002
[2]=> business-000003
)
```

**The issue is that I need it to show the last item inside the `$EmpExists=array();` to be `EmpNotExists` because the last `BusinessID` from `BusinessList` does not have any record of it in `EmployeeList`**. How can I do this right, please guide me if possible?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Could you see what am I doing wrong in my code above then?

Comment: I cant' even read this code. What about some indentation here?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks I shall keep in mind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the empty status of above question where `mysqli_fetch_assoc`does always yield a `true` one can use `mysqli_num_rows` instead for the above question, in the following way:

```
$EmpID = '';
$EmpExists = array();
$EmpIDRecord = array();
foreach ($BusinessIDforthis as $x) {
  $select_EmpID = "SELECT EmpID FROM EmployeeList WHERE BusinessID='{$x}';";
  $select_EmpID_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_EmpID);
  if (!$select_EmpID_query) {die ("Database query for searching EmpID failed.");}
 else
 {$EmpIDrows = mysqli_num_rows($select_EmpID_query);
  if ($EmpIDrows===0) {
    array_push($EmpExists, 'EmpNotExists');
    array_push($EmpIDRecord, 'Employee does not exist.');
   } else {
    array_push($EmpExists, 'EmpExists');
    array_push($EmpIDRecord, $EmpID);
   }
    $EmpIDrows= '';
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$select_EmpID_query = mysqli_query($connection, $select_EmpID);` will always return true unless theres a resource error which means that it will loop as many times as its true (3 rows from BusinessList = 3 loops). You should use `mysqli_num_rows()` instead.

Really, you should be using JOINs to obtain your data as such:

```
SELECT * FROM BusinessList AS BL
LEFT JOIN EmployeeList as EL ON BL.BusinessID = EL.BusinessID
ORDER BY BL.BusinessID ASC
```

Also, shouldnt `$EmpID = $EmpID_array["EmployeeID"];` this be `$EmpID = $EmpID_array["EmpID"];`?

Comment: Thanks friend, I didn't knew this.